# scala rename case class property dynamically

Tags: scala, scala-macros, case-class

I have an object

```
object Helper{
val fieldName = "fooBar
}
```

which provides the name for a field.
And a case class

```
case class BarBaz(fieldOne:Int, fieldTwo:String)
```

But instead of `fieldTwo`, I would like to refer to `Helper.fieldname` for the parameter name of the case class.

How can this be accomplished in Scala? Maybe via a macro? Or is there a simpler possibility?
I.e.

```
case class BarBaz(fieldOne:Int, Helper.fieldName:String)
```

would be the desired output, but that will not compile.

Comment: calling as BarBaz.fieldTwo or Helper.fieldName, aren't they the same? You have to create instance of both. Can you not change the field name of case class?

Comment: I want to be able to change the field name of the case class by modifying the val `fieldName`. Please see the edit.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but `Map[String, ?]` may be a simpler way to access things by means of a "dynamic identifier".

Comment: I need a case class for spark dataset to work. And this case class should be constructed at compile time to have an attribute of name Helper.fieldName

Comment: Could you please provide code snippet which you struggling with in relation to Spark, I would really assume your issue has nothing to do with dynamic field name creation etc. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't need to be runtime. Compile time and a macro are fine as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible as defining variables means pointing to some memory location where the value is stored. So the `compiler` sees a variable name as memory location address and not the value stored in that location and using a memory location for a variable name would not be allowed.

Comment: But could it be transformed to a compile time problem via macros?